# DIV refresh with index

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I ask for your help regarding the refreshment of my DIV.
When loading my page, _promo.php is called but does not update the data of this page.
Can you help me please ?
I don't know much about javascript

```
<?php include($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/includes/header.php"); ?>

<?php
try {
    $stat = $pdo->query( "SELECT * FROM tab_shop_produits");
    $i = 0;
    while ($data = $stat->fetch( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $reference = $data["reference"];
?>

<div id="promo_<?php echo $i; ?>" class="mb-2 text-end small text-success blink_"></div>
<input type="hidden" id="txt_reference_<?php echo $i; ?>" value="<?php echo $reference; ?>">
<?php 
        $i++;
    }
} catch(PDOException $e){
    echo "<div class='alert alert-danger'>".$e->getMessage()."</div>";
} 
?>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

function loadLog(i) {
   var reference   = document.getElementById("txt_reference_" + i).value;
   var intTotal   = parseInt('<?php echo $i; ?>');
   $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "_promo.php",
      cache: true,
      data: {reference: reference},
      error: function (e) {console.log('Ajax Error', e);alert('Erreur Ajax');},
      success: function(html){
         document.getElementById("promo_"+i).innerHTML = html;
         console.log(html);
         i=parseInt(i)+1;
         if(i<intTotal){setTimeout(loadLog(i), 1000);}
      }
   });
}
   setTimeout(loadLog('<?php echo $i; ?>'), 1000);
});
</script>

<?php include($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/includes/footer.php"); ?>
```

Comment: Also - how often is the content likely to be changing in the db to warrant updating every second ( or trying to )

Comment: I changed to 
setTimeout(loadLog('<?php echo $i; ?>'), 1000); 
and yes, every second

Comment: It's a countdown, so indeed, every second

Comment: So you hope to update every div generated in the `while` loop every second?

Comment: Have you looked in the debugger to see what, if anything, is being returned by `_promo.php`? Maybe it would also be useful to see that code

Comment: Yes, I hope to update the div every second indeed. The debugger does not show me any error, I have the content of _promo.php which is displayed when loading my index.php but that's it, each change, even in html in _promo.php does not update in index.php

Comment: each div (promo_0, promo_++) must display its promotion end date generated in _promo.php

Comment: OK - rather than sending a separate ajax request for every DIV every second there are better approaches I'd suggest. A single ajax request that fetches data for all div elements with the response as json (which you process in the callback function ) or perhaps Server Sent Events running in the background? We don't know what `_promo.php` does but it seems to return HTML content as the response.